# Pass a POJO as parameter in DAO query method to update subset of columns?

Tags: android, android-room

Room allows you to [return arbitrary POJOs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query.html) from your query methods as long as the fields of the POJO match the column names in the query result.

I am curious if it's possible to do the reverse.. pass in a POJO to a query method in order to update specific columns.

```
@Entity
data class Quiz(
        @PrimaryKey
        val id: Int,
        val completedCount: Int,
        val bestScore: Int,
        @Embedded val stats: Stats
)

data class Stats(
        val right: Int,
        val wrong: Int
)

@Dao
interface QuizDao {

    // OK.. passing in each column to be updated
    @Query("update quiz set `right` = :right, wrong = :wrong, where id = :id")
    fun updateStats(id: Int, right: Int, wrong: Int)

    // ERROR.. POJO fields can't be mapped to columns
    @Query("update quiz set `right`, wrong where id = :id")
    fun updateStats(id: Int, stats: Stats)
}
```

Comment: That does not work as the `query` you write is `sql` script and it only accepts primitive types. In case of `@Update` you don't write any sql query and I believe Room generates the query from fields of  `Stats`.

Comment: Haven't tested myself but have you tried using string templates. Something like  `update quiz set right = :${stats.right}, wrong = :${stats.wrong}, xp = :${stats.xp } where id = :id`

Comment: Tried it briefly, but doesn't appear to work. I think the `@Update` annotation with the `entity` attribute and a custom pojo is the way to go. I was able to get it to compile without errors, but I need to test it further to see if it's the actual solution. Updated question with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Room 2.2.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0-alpha01) (Jul 10, 2019):

> **Target Entity**: The DAO annnotations @Insert, @Update and @Delete now
>   has a new property targetEntity, that allows specifying the target
>   table the DAO method is meant to act on. This allows for the
>   parameters of those DAO methods to be arbitrary POJOs which will be
>   interpreted as partial entities. In practice, this allows partial
>   inserts, deletes and updates.

The property is actually named `entity` rather than `targetEntity`, and seems to work as intended for partial updates.

**Sample usage**

```
@Entity
data class User(
        @PrimaryKey
        val id: Int,
        val firstName: String,
        val lastName: String,
        @Embedded val favorites: Favorites
)

data class Favorites(
        var animal: String,
        var color: String
)

data class UserName(
        var id: Int,
        var firstName: String,
        var lastName: String
)

data class UserFavorites(
        var id: Int,
        @Embedded var favorites: Favorites
)

@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Update(entity = User::class)
    fun updateName(name: UserName)

    @Update(entity = User::class)
    fun updateFavorites(favorites: UserFavorites)
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Update#entity()) for the `entity` property, only the partial entity fields will be updated, which is what we want:

> The target entity of the update method.
>
> When this is declared, the update method parameters are interpreted as
>   partial entities when the type of the parameter differs from the
>   target. The POJO class that represents the entity must contain a
>   subset of the fields of the target entity along with its primary keys.
>
> Only the columns represented by the partial entity fields will be
>   updated if an entity with equal primary key is found.
>
> By default the target entity is interpreted by the method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify `@Update` and pass the POJO it will work.

```
@Update 
void updateUsers(List<User> users);
```

or

```
@Update
void updateUser(User user);
```

And your POJO should be

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")   
public class User
{
    //class menbers
}
```

This worked for me..

Comment: If I just pass the POJO, I get the following error: "Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it." Specifying the entity that the POJO "belongs to" does work, however.

Comment: in your pojo you have to add this annotation - @Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User
{ }

Comment: In my example, `User` is annotated as an entity, but only a subset of the columns need to be updated, thus the need to pass in a POJO such as `UserName` or `UserFavorites`. I updated the question title.

Comment: fetch the User object to be updated and modify the subset userName of User and pass that user object to update query.

Comment: In that case, every column will be updated, no? Even if only a few columns need to be.

Comment: only the changed column will get updated, but id field should not be null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196612/discussion-between-glucaio-and-akshatha-srinivas).